# Count vassal gained independence from conquering a duchy in war

Tags: crusader-kings-2

Is this supposed to happen? Why would conquering a duchy in war via claim work differently than usurping the title (if a count usurps a duchy and you are king they stay your vassal normally)?

Comment: It might be different if the duchy isn't a *de jure* part of your kingdom (I take it that you are a king and their direct liege). Was the duchy independent before the war? Or a part of a different Kingdom or Empire?